# JSON - object in array in object - how to parse through loop with JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

If I had this schema:

```
[{
    "Id": 2,
    "Prizes": [{
        "Id": 5,
        "Status": 0,
        "ClaimCode": "PN0016CXC1WPM64P",
        "User": {
            "FirstName": "John",
            "SecondName": "Doe",
        },
        "DrawId": 2,
        "PrizeId": 22,
        "Prize": null
    }]
}]
```

How could I get the first name or any value under object User that is in array prizes, that is in the main JSON?

I have tried this:

```
 const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
 response.Prizes[0].User.forEach(function(a) {
     output += `<li>${a.FirstName}</li>`;
 });
```

But getting the error undefined, I believe it can be extracted but only need right syntax. Or this can't be done with for loop?

Comment: `response` is an Array, not a plain Object. `forEach` should be used on an Array.

Comment: so is there any way I could loop through that? @PHPglue

Comment: `for(let key in response[0].Prizes[0].User)`, but I don't think you neeed a loop for this.

Comment: I have >1000 entries and I want to make a table so I believe I do need xD

Comment: I meant a loop for that User Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Response is an Array and User is an object, this should be working :

```
const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

response.map((resp) => {
    resp.Prizes.map((prize) => {
        output += `<li>${prize.User.FirstName}</li>`;

    })
})
```

Comment: still returning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: try it with loops added !

Comment: Are you sure about the schema? Is it case sensitive?

Comment: 100%sure I only remove some lines of info to shorten the code...it is case sensitive

Comment: can u post a log of the response object ?

Comment: just recheck...    xhr.send(); was not on right place... working, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an array of objects, and inside the object an array of values (`Prizes`), you can use nested [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) calls to get the internal values, wrap them with a string, and push to the `items` array:

```js
const response = [{"Id":2,"Prizes":[{"Id":5,"Status":0,"ClaimCode":"PN0016CXC1WPM64P","User":{"FirstName":"John","SecondName":"Doe"},"DrawId":2,"PrizeId":22,"Prize":null}]}];

const items = [];

response.forEach((o) => 
  o.Prizes.forEach((p) =>
    items.push(`<li>${p.User.FirstName}</li>`)
  ));
  
list.innerHTML = items.join('');
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have multidimensional array  and you need to use `Prizes` as inside of array.

So first you can combine all `Prizes` into one using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [`Spread_syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) then after you use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with join mehod to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const response = [{"Id":2,"Prizes":[{"Id":5,"Status":0,"ClaimCode":"PN0016CXC1WPM64P","User":{"FirstName":"John","SecondName":"Doe"},"DrawId":2,"PrizeId":22,"Prize":null}]}];

let res = response.reduce((r,{Prizes}) =>[...r,...Prizes],[]).map(({User})=>`<li>${User.FirstName}</li>`).join('');

document.querySelector('ul').innerHTML =res ;
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```